# Submit multiple forms inside foreach loop LARAVEL 8

Tags: php, laravel

i have form inside foreach loop and i want to grab the values in my controller.
the input of the text work's fine (i can get the value in the request) but the input image no !!

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
 <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 category">
  <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin')}}"
     class="card" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     @csrf
     <input type="file" id="img" class="upload_img" name="img">
     <label for="img">
        <img src="img/{{$category->img}}" alt="pizza">
     </label>
     <input name="title" type="text" value="{{$category->name}}">
     <input class="category_id" name="id" type="text" value="{{$category->id}}">
     <div class="btns">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="remove" class="remove">remove</button>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="save" class="save">save</button>
     </div>
  </form>
 </div>
@endforeach
```

when i dd($request->all()) it works for the first form but the other no.

how can i get the image of each form submitted

my controller :

```
    class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return  view('admin.index',[
            'categories' => Category::all(),
        ]);
    }
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());

    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're trying to do, but you can't submit multiple forms at once. If you want to send all the data at once, just use one form. Other than that, your code will generate multiple elements with the same id's, which is invalid in HTML. Element id's _must_ be unique within a document. And file-inputs aren't a part of the normal POST data so try fetching those with `$request->file()`. Read the [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your input

just change name="img" to name ="img[]"  and add attribute multiple="multiple"  .

Answer (score 0):

The only way for your method to work would be for the image to be a separate model or for it to be a migration that derives from a category and another migration such as post or product. This way you can use a `hasMany` or `belongTo` to allow, depending on your relationship, several images to be inserted for the same id, but apart from that I don't see any other solution. I can give you an example for the management of users and their roles, if you want, and you can adapt.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the form inside the loop. Make one form outside the loop, and name each file input:

```
<input type="file" id="img" class="upload_img" name="img[]">
```

then you can do a

```
foreach($request->img as $img)
{
  //save...
}
```

to access them individually